# finding a possible equation systen given a solution set

Tags: matrices

if given these vectors:
[vectors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZp2Z.png) ( u,v,w)
how can I find an equation systen with this general solution set :
[solution group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLPof.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. In order to avoid downvotes, please format your question using Mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: "Group" is a **very different** thing in mathematics. Call it what it is: solution *set* .